# How to calculate total ip's of a subnet in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet

Recently we got an issue of IP running out in VPC due to huge IP's consumed by ENI. I need to write a script in boto3, to trigger an alert if total ip usage increases around 80% or something.

Hence I need to know the Total ip's allocated in a subnet in VPC. I need the total count of used IP's and free IP's.

Please share the boto3 commands for doing it.

Comment: You can use python script with os.system and "aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters SubnetId=subnet-b61f49f0 | grep PublicIp | wc -l " and then compare output with pre definited number then trigger email using python smtp module or SES.

Comment: What is the pre-defined number? I don't want to hard code any number. I need to extract the total count. Also, is it like the total ENI Ip's + available-ip-address-count(describe_subnets) gives the total IP's of subnet?

Comment: By above command, you get used public IP, first you may have to separately stored or extract total ip by another command which is pre definied number here then compare both so you will get ip usage out of total.

Comment: The subnet mask determines the number of IP addresses in a subnet, but subtract 5 for reserved addresses. For example, a `/24` subnet would have `256 - 5 = 251` available addresses.

Answer (score 6):

The awscli ec2 [describe-subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-subnets.html) call will actually return you the number of unused private IPv4 addresses in the subnet. The  IPv4  addresses for any stopped instances are considered unavailable.

For example:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets \
    --subnet-ids subnet-c0c1a23a \
    --query "Subnets[0].AvailableIpAddressCount"
```

Sample output:

```
249
```

To calculate the total number of usable IPs in the subnet 10.0.0.0/24 or more generally a /N:

```
10.0.0.0/24 => 2**(32-24) - 5
10.0.0.0/N  => 2**(32-N) - 5
```

Note that you subtract 5 because the first four IP addresses and the last IP address in each subnet CIDR block are [reserved by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#VPC_Sizing), and cannot be assigned to an instance.

And, for good measure, a Python script:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

# Use this for specific subnets
# filters = [{'Name':'subnet-id', 'Values':['subnet-c0c1a23a']}]
# subnets = ec2.subnets.filter(Filters=filters)

# Use this for all subnets
subnets = ec2.subnets.all()

for subnet in list(subnets):
    free_ips = subnet.available_ip_address_count
    n = int(subnet.cidr_block.split('/')[1])
    cidr_ips = 2**(32-n)
    used_ips = cidr_ips - free_ips
    print('{:s}: cidr={:d}, aws used=5, you used={:d}, free={:d}'.\
        format(subnet.id, cidr_ips, used_ips - 5, free_ips))
```

Sample output:

```
subnet-1eb2e345: cidr=256, free=251, aws used=5, you used=0
subnet-c0c1a23a: cidr=256, free=249, aws used=5, you used=2
```

Comment: Thanks for good update. Looks good but stuck at a point.   I have a subnet with CIDR 10.97.32.0/21 which results in 2048 IP's .. ( Ignoring 5 ) it will round to 2043 IP's.  However in Network interface section, I can see a total of 1,697 under the subnet and total available IP4 in subnet section is 245. There are around 101 IP's which are missing.  Is it like Total subnet IP's = ENI IP's + Available IP's + Reserved IP's(5) ? If so, its not matching .

Comment: Any chance that you can identify an unavailable IP that isn't listed in the Network Interfaces list for that subnet? Wonder if certain classes of managed AWS resource running do not appear in that list. Other than EC2, what are you running in that subnet?

Comment: I was refreshing subnet page and ENI page .. Probably due to some metrics refresh the count was not capturing properly. I invoked everything through a lambda and worked fine.

Comment: Yes Jarmod. Your suggestion helped me.