# Error creating Lambda function - The subnet is out of IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, terraform

We have a terraform script to create a lambda function in aws. This lambda function uses a custom bucket from S3.

**The script below runs perfectly when I put `"Resource": "*"`.**

We need to specify a custom resource that aws lambda function can access on S3.

Our aws_iam_policy is configured this way:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_policy" {
  name = "lambda-s3-policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*",
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-mock-bucket/example-folder/*"
    }
  ]
} 
 EOF
}
```

When the script runs, this error appears:

```
Error: Error applying plan:
1 error(s) occurred:
* aws_lambda_function.func_loader: 1 error(s) occurred:
* aws_lambda_function.func_loader: Error creating Lambda function: InvalidParameterValueException: The subnet subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is out of IP addresses.
{
  RespMetadata: {
    StatusCode: 400,
    RequestID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  Message_: "The subnet subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is out of IP addresses.",
  Type: "User"
}
Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
```

I already checked the permissions, the subnet ip range limits, but it is all good to go.

Comment: You said IP range limits , did you actually mean total unused Ips? Error message clearly says that subnets is out of IPs, even if one subnet runs out of IPs, we will get that error.

Comment: The error message doesn't appear to be related to permissions. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320836/how-to-calculate-total-ips-of-a-subnet-in-aws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These permissions:

```
   "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
   "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
   "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
   "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
   "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
   "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
```

Can't be restricted to this resource:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-mock-bucket/example-folder/*"
```

What you have done is given your Lambda function permission to call those EC2 actions, as long as it is calling those actions on an S3 bucket, which obviously makes no sense. You probably need to split the IAM policy into multiple statements, like so:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*",
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-mock-bucket/example-folder/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I split these permissions and it works! Thank you! Silly mistake.